# Get Package Id in UWP Optional Package

Tags: uwp

I need to get Package Id of Optional Package. But It get Package Id of Main App when I use `Package.Current.Id.Name` in the Optional Package.

How can I get the Package Id of Optional Package in the Optional Package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **Package.Current** to get the main app package, then get a list of dependencies for the main package. Finally you could iterate the list of the optional packages and find the specified optional package.

As follows:

```
var optionalPackage = Package.Current.Dependencies.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsOptional);
string name= optionalPackage.Id.Name;
```

**Update:**
I have tested it. It is suitable to call in Optional package. For multiple packages, you could distinguish them through different DisplayName.(Open the **Package.appxmanifest** file of optional package to find DisplayName)

```
var optionalPackage = Package.Current.Dependencies.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DisplayName== "OptionalPackageWithPageToShow");
```

Comment: I need to get it in the Optional Package. And I have more than one optional package.

Comment: @Hancel Lin I have updated the answer for you, please check it.